# Toggle button font color and drawableft selector

Tags: android, xamarin

Xamarin, android.
I made a selector which changes background colors:

```html
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape>
      <solid
          android:color="#aaaaac"/>

      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="5dp"
          android:top="5dp"
          android:right="5dp"
          android:bottom="5dp" />
    </shape>
    <drawable
      drawableLeft="@drawable/male"/>
  </item>
  <item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape>

      <solid
          android:color="#357fca" />

      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="5dp"
          android:top="5dp"
          android:right="5dp"
          android:bottom="5dp" />
    </shape>
    <drawable
          drawableLeft="@drawable/male_pushed"/>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Besides that, I also want to change drawableft and text colors as follows.
If - `android:state_checked="false"` 
then
`android:textColor="#000000"` and  `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/male"`

if - `android:state_checked="true"` 
then `android:textColor="#ffffff"` and

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/male_pushed"
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set multiple properties like `drawableLeft`, `textColor` etc using Single selector. You should create selector for each attributes.

Create

1. **drawable_left_selector.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/male"/>
       <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/male_pushed"/>
   </selector>
   ```
2. **text_color_selector.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="#000000"/>
       <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#ffffff"/>
   </selector>
   ```
3. **toggle_selector.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_checked="false">
           <shape>
               <solid android:color="#aaaaac"/>
               <corners android:radius="6dp" />
               <padding
                   android:left="5dp"
                   android:top="5dp"
                   android:right="5dp"
                   android:bottom="5dp" />
          </shape>
       </item>
       <item android:state_checked="true">
           <shape>

               <solid android:color="#357fca" />
               <corners android:radius="6dp" />
               <padding
                   android:left="5dp"
                   android:top="5dp"
                   android:right="5dp"
                   android:bottom="5dp" />
           </shape>
       </item>
   </selector>
   ```
4. **Set `ToggleButton`**

   ```
   <ToggleButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
       android:drawableLeft="@drawable/drawable_left_selector"
       android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector" />
   ```